# CSS Conditional Statements

Tags: html, css

I know this is possible for css conditional formatting:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
   link/css style goes here
<![endif]-->
```

But is is possible to have an OR statement in there?  Such as:

```
<!--[if !IE or !Opera]>
    link/css style goes here
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind IE (and only old versions of it) is the only browser that supports these statements. It is best to write cross-browser CSS

Comment: Also, while this is a bit old, this closely related question might provide additional insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie , also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454863/what-is-better-css-hacks-or-browser-detection?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional Comments are an IE-specific feature, and will be ignored by opera etc.

They do support "or", however in the form of a pipe like so;

```
<!-- [if (IE 6)|(IE 7)]>
    this is only seen by IE 6 and 7
<![endif]-->
```

[source: msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*EDIT*

As commented, it is indeed preferable to write cross-browser-compatible CSS when possible, and use conditional comments only as a last resort. To make life easier, be sure to avoid [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and use feature detection over user agent sniffing. Check out the [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library which helps with the latter.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something :) Had no idea I could do that. I'd just like to add it is generally better to write CSS that works in all browsers to begin with (or, degrades gracefully)